# Add special beamer slide using RMarkdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, beamer

I want to produce a beamer presentation from a RMarkdown file.
I am in this case using this beautiful template: https://github.com/matze/mtheme

How in markdown can you specify that you want to insert, not a "normal" slide, by a special one, such as an appendix slide, or a standout slide?

This template contains a standout slide that I would like to use as final slide as they do in their demo slides (http://mirrors.standaloneinstaller.com/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/beamer-contrib/themes/metropolis/demo/demo.pdf)

In beamer, I would do:

```
\begin{frame}[standout]
Questions?
\end{frame}
```

What is the equivalent in Markdown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting frame options is pretty straight forward:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: beamer_presentation
theme: "metropolis"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

##  {.standout}
Questions?
````

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much ! It works for the frame options.
How should I do for appendix slides?
In beamer, all slides inserted after "\appendix" are appendix slides

Comment: So far, I have not found a solution for the `\appendix` problem. It should be somehow possible to include appendix slides as a seperate file via `includes: after_body: appendix.md` though.